# constexpr ID for class supporting equality comparison

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++14, constexpr

I need to create a unique `constexpr` ID for my C++ classes. A further requirement is that these IDs should be comparable for equality (even better if they can be compared with `>` and `<`.

A simple solution comes to mind:

```
template <typename T>
struct IDMaker {
    static int i;
    static constexpr void * id = &i;
}
```

The trouble with this approach is that the following fails to compile in a `constexpr` context:

```
IDMaker<int>::id == IDMaker<double>::id;
```

It appears that `id` is `constexpr` but its comparison is not. I've experimented with this a bit, and there's essentially nothing useful that you could do with this `id` within a `constexpr` context. (Edit: This is an error in GCC 5.3 and according to dyp in the comments, clang doesn't complain about this. Is it a GCC bug? or is clang being too permissive?)

To give a little bit of context, I need this to be able to use `constexpr` functions for metaprogramming, so that I can reuse the same logic at runtime. For instance, I want to be able to write a function that takes two type lists and returns an array containing the indices of the elements in the second list matching those in the first list. If I could obtain IDs for the classes, I could easily implement this as a `constexpr` function receiving two arrays of type IDs. In addition to reusing the `constexpr` function at runtime, I hope that this will also speed-up my compile times.

I actually have sort of a solution, but it involves some macro magic; Essentially, I use a macro to reflect the names of the classes and namespaces as `constexpr const char * name(){return #NewType;}` I can also access the reflection class of a class's namespace and get its name. I ended up writing a `constexpr` hash function:

```
constexpr size_t hash(const char *str) {
    size_t result{0};
    for(size_t i =0; str[i]!=0; ++i) {
        ...
    }
    return result;
}
```

With this function I can hash the complete name of a class and obtain a `constexpr` `size_t`, and it works. I have two problems with this approach though:

1) How bad will my compile times get when I have 1000 classes? Can you recommend a fast hash function?
2) How can I avoid hash collisions, or at least get an early error when the collision happens?

Comment: This might just be a gcc bug, or a missing feature. clang doesn't complain about comparing your ids at compile time.

Comment: @dyp Interesting, I should mention that in the question then.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69681 for function pointers

Comment: @dyp nice catch! Though I can't conclude from the link whether this is considered a GCC bug, or is it really supposed to be rejected according to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

To generate an ID for your classes at compile time, you could use a pointer to function. I implemented it as a template meta function that return a pointer to function and take a type as parameter:

```
template<typename T>
void id_gen(){}

using type_id_t = void(*)(void);

template<typename T>
constexpr type_id_t type_id = &id_gen<T>;
```

Since every instantiation of the function `id_gen` has different addresses, we can use it as a unique identifier!

Then, you can make some syntax sugar for your classes:

```
template<typename Crtp>
struct Identified {
    static constexpr type_id_t ID = type_id<Crtp>;
};
```

Now to identify your classes you just have to use inheritance:

```
struct A : Identified<A> {};
struct B : Identified<B> {};
```

The advantages of this solution:

- no collisions
- very fast compilation time
- easy to use in `std::map`

Cons of this solution:

- The ID generation is compile time only
- You cannot predict the values

Comment: I've just gave it a chance, but unfortunately your suggestion suffers from the same problem as the first solution I've tried, namely, GCC 5.3 complains that `error: ‘(func1 == func2)’ is not a constant expression` when I try to compare them in a constexpr function.

Comment: I've just tried with a `static_assert` as well, GCC 5.3 again complains `error: ‘(id_gen<A> == id_gen<B>)’ is not a constant expression`

Comment: It'd be much nicer if a variation of this solution worked, it would be much simpler and faster than the hash-based alternative.

Comment: Well... Seems I hit the same wall as yours.

Comment: Reading other comments, it's seems like a GCC bug. I'll leave this answer for others that use clang out there.